# PHP to ASP.NET / C#

Tags: php, asp.net

I am trying to convert the following to ASP.NET C#

```
    <?php

/* Configuration Start */

$thumb_directory = 'img/thumbs';
$orig_directory = 'img/original';

$stage_width=600;   // How big is the area the images are scattered on
$stage_height=400;

/* Configuration end */

$allowed_types=array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png');
$file_parts=array();
$ext='';
$title='';
$i=0;

/* Opening the thumbnail directory and looping through all the thumbs: */

$dir_handle = @opendir($thumb_directory) or die("There is an error with your image directory!");

$i=1;
while ($file = readdir($dir_handle)) 
{
    /* Skipping the system files: */
    if($file=='.' || $file == '..') continue;

    $file_parts = explode('.',$file);
    $ext = strtolower(array_pop($file_parts));

    /* Using the file name (withouth the extension) as a image title: */
    $title = implode('.',$file_parts);
    $title = htmlspecialchars($title);

    /* If the file extension is allowed: */ 
    if(in_array($ext,$allowed_types))
    {
        /* Generating random values for the position and rotation: */
        $left=rand(0,$stage_width);
        $top=rand(0,400);
        $rot = rand(-40,40);

        if($top>$stage_height-130 && $left > $stage_width-230)
        {
            /* Prevent the images from hiding the drop box */
            $top-=120+130;
            $left-=230;
        }

        /* Outputting each image: */

        echo '
        <div id="pic-'.($i++).'" class="pic" style="top:'.$top.'px;left:'.$left.'px;background:url('.$thumb_directory.'/'.$file.') no-repeat 50% 50%; -moz-transform:rotate('.$rot.'deg); -webkit-transform:rotate('.$rot.'deg);">
        <a class="fancybox" rel="fncbx" href="'.$orig_directory.'/'.$file.'" target="_blank">'.$title.'</a>
        </div>';
    }
}

/* Closing the directory */
closedir($dir_handle);

?>
```

In ASP.NET how do i loop through a series of images from a directory? 
What does "explode" mean in PHP?
Is this a do while loop?

Comment: What is your question/problem?

Comment: oppps i forgot to add the question.. let me add it.. sorry one sec

Comment: Explode : http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help you. It has complete code samples:

**How to: Enumerate Directories and Files**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997370.aspx